# Como Digitar em um Select?

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

Como posso fazer com que um `select` funcione também como um campo de pesquisa? Tipo, o cliente digita como se estivesse digitando em um `input text` por exemplo, e as opções do `select` vão sendo filtradas conforme o que ele digitou. Não sei bem se seria um `select`, mas preciso fazer isso de alguma forma.

Atualmente está assim:

```
<select id="id_mfuncao" name="id_mfuncao" class="form-control">
   @foreach($mfuncoes as $mfuncao)
      <option value="{{ $mfuncao->id }}">{{ $mfuncao->nome }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Eu faço isso direto com um campo `text` e um `ul` escondido e vazio embaixo. Daí busca os dados via `ajax` da base de dados e faço um `append()` com o `li` dentro com os valores.

Comment: Você quer um campo texto onde o que a pessoa digite seja usado como filtro em uma busca? em algum campo específico?

Comment: então, tenho um select com umas 500 opções que vem do banco, preciso que a pessoa possa digitar ali pra n ficar correndo o select caso saiba ao menos parte do nome

Comment: Acho q n preciso usar ajax nesse caso @Zoom, pois os dados já estão carregados. Só preciso ir filtrando

Comment: Bom, mas não tem como você digitar num `select`, você tem que **mascarar** e mostrar apenas o que precisa. Na minha cabeça você teria que montar o `combobox` por ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloquei no Snippet apenas para organizar.

O JS é simples, no seletor `#q` que é o campo, cada letra que digito é feita uma busca na base de dados e no `success` eu mostro esses resultados por meio de um `append`.

Na função `postConsulta` no **Controller** eu retorno um `array`, e não `json`.

```js
// Resultados da Pesquisa
$('#q').on('keyup', function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  var res = $("#resultados");
  var row = $("#resultados > ul");
  $.ajax({
    url: urlBase + 'consulta/', 
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    data: {
      str: str
    },
    success: function(result) {
      res.css('display', 'block');
      row.html('');
      if (str != '') {
        $.each(result, function(index, value) {
          if (value == 'Produtos') {
            row.append('<li class="subtitle">Produtos</li>');
          } else if (value == 'Serviços') {
            row.append('<li class="subtitle">Serviços</li>');
          } else if (value != '')
            row.append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
        });
      } else {
        str = '';
        res.css('display', 'none');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.consulta {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  div#resultados {
    display: none;
    ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      width: 410px;
      text-indent: 14px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-left: 34px;
      li {
        font-family: @avenir;

font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 23px;
        a {
          color: #FFF;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        &:hover {
          a {
            color: @yellow;

          }
        }
        &.subtitle {
          color: #FFF;
          font-weight: bolder;
          font-size: 17px;
          list-style-type: disc;
          a {
            color: #000;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="consulta">
  <label>BUSCA AVANÇADA</label>
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q" placeholder="Pesquisar por produtos/serviços">
  <div id="resultados">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mas assim só vai parecer as opções se o cara digitar algo, certo? se sim, teria como al mesmo tempo que ele pode digitar, ele poder tbm ver todas as funções disponíveis?

Comment: poxa eu já vi isso q eu quero em algum lugar mas agr n lembro, me pareceu tão simples, talvez um plugin. Era ou "parecia" realmente um select com a setinha do lado e tals, so q podendo digitar nele para filtrar.

Comment: Ver que funções Raylan ?

Comment: ver todas as opções*

Comment: Sim, você pode controlar isso pela consulta no controller, uma consulta que traz tudo e uma só do que o usuário está pesquisando. Faz um `merge` no array e traz. Daí no JS você tem que dar um jeito de deixar esteticamente legal.

Comment: consegui colocar aqui, vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é um select, isso pode ser tratado de acordo com a linguagem que está utilizando.

Uma forma de fazer isso é com o jQuery, com a função keypress:

```
$("#filtro").keypress(function () {
    // ação a ser tomada
});
```

O select é que vai trazer os resultados por trás.

Comment: Desculpe @Bruno, mas não consegui entender como aplicar essa solução, poderia me dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Eu apenas dei um exemplo simples, da uma olhada em: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/